# tkz-euclide: How can I label a point with white border around the letter

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tkz-euclide

[image]

[image]

I want to label a point like L_A in the above picture (the letter is above the line). I tried "fill=white", but it creates a big white square around the letter (the point C in the second picture). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please can you give a minimal code so that we can answer ?A solution if `tkz-euclide` can't satisfy what you want is to use `TikZ`. What is exactly your problem ?  Do you want a circular background ?

Comment: try [inner sep=0]

Comment: `contour` package can put an outline edge around characters.

Comment: @BlackMild thanks a lot, that's what i want.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks!!!! That's exactly what i mean